# how to make messages marked read through POP3 using spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration, pop3

Ty for reading my issue.

I am currently using spring integration V3.0.7 for retrieving mails from the specific email address.All things went smoothly until I found this on the instructions of the schema of XML configuration files where I load the parameters into main test case:

```
<xsd:attribute name="should-mark-messages-as-read" type="xsd:string" use="optional" default="true">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
<![CDATA[
Specify whether mail messages should be marked as read after being retrieved (**Not supported in POP3**). Messages are marked after retrieval but before they are processed. If you wish to mark a message after completion of message processing, use transaction synchronization instead.
]]>
</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>
```

But I am using POP3 protocol, which means no shortcut to achieve my goal: mark all pulled-out mails with READ status.

How could I possibly accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported by the POP3 protocol.

POP3 is designed such that clients are expected to retrieve and delete emails from the "post office", not leave them there.

You need to use IMAP instead for this additional functionality.

Comment: Is it possible if you make an enquiry about which protocol the user authorized to the mailbox (i.e. I disabled the IMAP but enabled POP3) and verify it so you can make an alternative way of retrieving mails from that mailbox/inbox?Thank you.